# Designing a form

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I'm currently searching for ways I can best display results like a report coupled with a graphical 3D diagram on the right displaying statistics. I saw an ad for Telerik -- is there any other better ways I can get this done?

Design is really important at this point for me; more than the coding.

It would be nice if you guys could provide me with options I can choose from for designing such as MVC WPF, WinForm , Telerik, etc.  I'd appreciate any really nice design choices for creating such forms.

Comment: you need to be more specific. what are you designing for? have you no requirements?

Comment: There are several beginner articles at www.codeproject.com I think you should start there and get a better understanding of .net development in general before you start thinking on 3D, wpf and these thing. I highly recommend you to understand what you can do with .net as well as other platforms before you start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for help creating reports. Telerik and Developer Express (DevExpress) are two prominent companies that create controls for WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET. Both companies have controls that will help you create reports, charts, and nicely formatted grids.

[DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/)

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/)

Before you get to that, you have to decide if you're going to write your app in WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc.  The one you choose has more to do with how you need your users to access your app than how the design will be laid out.

Once you know that, then you can look companies like I've mentioned above to supply you with prettier reporting controls.